# assign array to html data

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I have such code:

```
$users = User::lists('email', 'id');

<dd class="editable users" data-type="select" data-source="{{ $users }}">
```

And I get error: Array to string conversion. I understand that {{ $users }} is like  and you cant echo array, so how I can assign this $users array to data-source?

Comment: Use loop or get by specific index number?

Comment: If you need that for some javascript processing then maybe encode it to json format

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<dd class="editable users" data-type="select" data-source="{{ json_encode($users) }}">
```

And in javascript use JSON.parse(...) do decode value to json object.